# enabling submit button based on input

Tags: javascript, html, django

There is a form having a textarea and a submit button
I want the submit to be enabled and disabled based on 'if there is any input in the textarea'
both the submit and content is being selected correctly (ill send a screenshot of it)
JS file:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',() => {

    document.querySelector('#all-posts').addEventListener('click', () => loadAllPosts())
    if (document.querySelector('#following') != null){
        document.querySelector('#following').addEventListener('click', () => loadFollowing())
    }

    loadAllPosts();
});

function loadAllPosts(){

    document.querySelector('#allPosts-view').style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector('#following-view').style.display = 'none';

    fetch('/api/post')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        const posts = data.data.posts;
        const postCards = posts.map(post => {
            let likeBtnClass = 'fa fa-heart-o';
            if (post.liked_by_user) {
                likeBtnClass = 'fa fa-heart';
            }
            const on = new Date(post.posted_on).toLocaleString('en-US', { 
                hour: 'numeric',
                minute: 'numeric', 
                month: 'long', 
                day: 'numeric', 
                year: 'numeric', 
                timeZone: 'UTC' 
            });
            return `
                <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">${post.posted_by.username}</h5>
                        <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="font-size: 12px;">${on}</p>
                        <hr style="border: none; height: 1px; background-color: #FFFFF0; margin: 0px;">
                        <p class="card-text" style="margin-top: 5px; font-size: 25px;">${post.content}</p>
                        <div class="like-container">
                            <i id="like-btn" class="${likeBtnClass}" style="font-size:24px; cursor:pointer; margin-right: 10px;"></i>
                            <p class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted" style="margin-top: 0.5rem; padding: 0px; font-size: 12px;">${post.likes}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            `;
        });
        document.querySelector('#allPosts-view').innerHTML += postCards.join('');
    })
    .catch(err => console.error(err));

    const likeBtnsContainer = document.querySelector('#allPosts-view');
    likeBtnsContainer.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    if (event.target.matches('#like-btn')) {
        event.target.classList.toggle('fa-heart');
        event.target.classList.toggle('fa-heart-o');
    }
    });

    if (document.querySelector('#newPost-form') !== null) {
        const submit = document.querySelector('#newPost-submit');
        const content = document.querySelector('#newPost-content');

        submit.disabled = true;
      
        content.addEventListener('keyup', () => {
          if (content.value.length > 0) {
            submit.disabled = false;
          } else {
            submit.disabled = true;
          }
        });
    }
      
}


function loadFollowing() {

    document.querySelector('#allPosts-view').style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector('#following-view').style.display = 'block';
}
```

HTML file:

```
{% extends "network/layout.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Index {% endblock %}
{% block js %} <script src="{% static 'network/index.js' %}"></script> {% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <div id="allPosts-view">
        {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
        <div class="card text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 5px;" >
            <form id="newPost-form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="NEW-POST" style="font-size: 20px;">New Post</label>
                    <hr style="border: none; height: 1px; background-color: #FFFFF0; margin: 0px 0px 15px 0px;">
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="newPost-content" rows="3" style="resize: none; height: 120px;"></textarea>
                </div>
                <input id="newPost-submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #007BFF;" value="Post">
            </form>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </div>

    <div id="following-view">
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

I'm using django here but I don't think that is matters in this scenario

[submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOFBL.png)

[textarea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f931e.png)

Issue:
The submit button is getting disabled but even when i type something in the text area the submit button is disabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can gain this functionality by using [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), like so:

```js
const myTextarea = document.getElementById("myTextarea");
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton");

myTextarea.addEventListener("input", () => {
  if (myTextarea.value.trim() === "") {
    myButton.disabled = true;
  } else {
    myButton.disabled = false;
  }
});
```

```html
<form>
  <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
  <button id="myButton" type="submit" disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```

In this code, we're using the addEventListener method to listen for changes to the textarea's value. When the value changes, we check if it's empty (i.e., contains only whitespace), and if it is, we disable the submit button using the disabled property. If the textarea is not empty, we enable the submit button.

Note that we're using the trim method to remove leading and trailing whitespace from the textarea's value before checking if it's empty. This ensures that a user can't submit the form with only whitespace in the textarea.